# Is it possible to share tables for some parts of a inheritance hierarchy but not other in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

We have a series of entities that all map to the same table.

Something like the following

```
public abstract class Transaction { // Properties omitted }
public class Allowance : Transaction { // ... }
public class Charge : Transaction { // ... }
```

Then we have configured the model as follows:

```
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Transaction> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        builder.ToTable("Transactions");
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Charge> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(p => p.AccountId).HasColumnName(nameof(Transaction.AccountId));
        builder.Property(t => t.TransactionType).HasColumnName(nameof(Charge.TransactionType));
        builder.HasIndex("TransactionType", "Discriminator"); // Only defining index on one of them because it is otherwise generated twice
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Allowance> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(p => p.AccountId).HasColumnName(nameof(Transaction.AccountId));
        builder.Property(t => t.TransactionType).HasColumnName(nameof(Allowance.TransactionType));
    }
```

This works just fine, I have a table Transactions, with a discriminator and a shared colum for `AccountId` and `TransactionType`

Now we need to add a class `WriteOff` which is also a Transaction, but for persistance purposes we want it to live in another table than `Transactions` (different life time governance basically).

```
public class WriteOff : Transaction { // .. }
```

I have tried adding it as above and then doing something like

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<WriteOff> builder)
{
   builder.ToTable("WriteOffTransactions");
}
```

And various other mutations, but in all cases I end up screwing up my original mapping of Charge/Allowance.

Is it possible to achieve what I want with EF Core (currently on 7)? Or will we just have to accept that WriteOff is in fact NOT a Transaction when it comes to the readmodel and create a separate hierarchy for it?